# I wanted to use Firebase UI Auth in my android app but when I add the dependency, the gradle shows an error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

Comment: share your manifest

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package.name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Answer (score 1):

Check the [official doc:](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/version-2.3.0#upgrading-dependencies)

> If you would like to use a newer version of one of FirebaseUI's transitive dependencies, such as Firebase, Play services, or the Android support libraries, **you need to add explicit compile declarations in your build.gradle for all of FirebaseUI's dependencies** at the version you want to use.

For example if you want to use Play services/Firebase version `FOO` and support libraries version `BAR` add the following extra lines for each FirebaseUI module you're using:

**Auth:**

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$FOO"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$FOO"

compile "com.android.support:design:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$BAR"
```

**Database:**

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$FOO"

compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$BAR"
```

**Storage:**

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$FOO"

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$BAR"
```

In your case you have to add to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0."
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0."
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0."
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0."
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0."
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0."
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0."
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your FirebaseUI Version as shown below.

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
```

Comment: Added, synced the gradle again but the problem still persists.

Comment: It also says all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 26.0.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

Answer (score 0):

**add**

> 'com.android.support:design-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: where do I change it? There's no such line in my app gradle file.